# unequal length data frame column replacment

Tags: r

Given this two unequal size data frames, would like to compare `dfx$v1` to `dfy$p2` where they match, replace `dfy$p2` with value of `dfx$v2`

```
dfx <- data.frame( v1 = c(1,2,3),
                   v2 = c("a1","a2","a3"))

dfy <- data.frame( p1 = c("c1","d1","e1","f1","g1","h1"),
                   p2 = sample(c(1:3)),
                   p3 = c("c3","d3","e3","f2","g2","h2"),
                   p4 = c("c4","d4","e4","f4","g3","h3") 
                   )
```

Out put should look like this:

```
> dfy
p1 p2 p3 p4
c1  a2 c3 c4
d1  a1 d3 d4
e1  a3 e3 e4
f1  a2 f2 f4
g1  a1 g2 g3
h1  a3 h2 h3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `match` to get the matching indices, then subset the replacement column by them

```
dfy$p2 <- with(dfx, v2[match(dfy$p2, v1)])
```